# Permission to get wifi scanresults independent of LocationService

Tags: android

I'm looking for the permission which enables the WifiSettings to [retrieve ScanResults](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.html#getScanResults()) with deactivated location services.

I already had a look on [settings manifest](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Settings/+/master/AndroidManifest.xml) and tried android.permission.NETWORK_SETTINGS but this did not work out. Any suggestions?

It's for a custom rom. So I can get permissions with level signed

AndroidVersion = 6.0

Device = Samsung Tab 3

Answer (score 0):

you have to add the following permission:

> Manifest.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE

After that run following code snippet to start a scan

```
((WifiManager) getSystemService(WIFI_SERVICE)).startScan()
```

After that Register a BroadcastReceiver to listen to

> SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION

When a broadcast is received, call:

```
((WifiManager) getSystemService(WIFI_SERVICE)).getScanResults()
```

Comment: This works for standard use cases, but as soon as you deactivate the location services the return from getScanResults() will be empty. I'm looking for way how the Android settings are doing it without the location service activated. It's for a custom rom

Comment: on which version of android you are testing?

Comment: It's Android 6.0

Comment: you have to set targetsdk to 21 or lower becasue it's not working on higher api's, seems like a bug in android

Comment: that's unfortunately not possible. Probably it's intended, as the scan results are position relevant. Theoretically you could calculate the users location.

Comment: yes, you are right. If its a bug it should be resolved in next version but they didn't

Comment: No, it also happens in newer versions. Somewhere I have even seen that the location service has to be activated. Unfortunately I currently don't find the page in the Android documentation